# Superscrollorama fade in/out scrolling

Tags: jquery

I'm using superscrollorama to try and get a fade in and out effect upon scrolling, but apparently it just goes on to the fade out animation before I can even display it fading in....

here's my code

```
    controller.addTween('.main', 
    (new TimelineLite())
        .append([
            TweenMax.from($('.fade'), 1, 
                {css:{opacity: 0}})
        ]),0,1200
        .append([
            TweenMax.from($('.fade'), 1, 
                {css:{opacity: 1}})
            ]),0,400
);
```

As you can see, I've made an offset timing of 1200 pixels to the fade in, with an immediate duration of 0 to the animation.  The fadeout is the same duration, but the offset is 400 (should it be set to 1600, to account for the fade in offset?)

With this it just goes right into the fade out.

Answer (score 2):

From the top of my head, that would probably give you a syntax error, since the duration and offset are properties passed to the addTween function, not properties of the TweenMax function.